# Is it possible to map subdirectory as root (spring)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm implementing a web application using Spring MVC. The root path is WEB-INF/views and here I have some jsp and some subdirectories containing other jsp. It is possible to map WEB-INF/views/{some dir} into WEB-INF/views/ ? My purpose is to refer pages only with name. For example I want to write :

```
<c:url value="/myJsp.jsp"></c:url>
```

instead of

```
<c:url value="/dir1/dir2/myJsp.jsp"></c:url>
```

Obviusly I want to mantain directories structure.

Comment: When you say "the root path" do you mean the `prefix` used by the `InternalResourceViewResolver`?

Comment: Yes, prefix is set as WEB-INF/views, so for me it's the root...